# How to style elements inside fancy box

Tags: php, html, fancybox

Its my first time using modal windows. And I'm currently using fancy box. But the problem is I can't style the elements inside of it. Using the usual styling using css.
I'm calling regprod.php which is a create form and put it inside the modal window. But I can't see the style that I applied.

```
<a id="inline"  href="http://localhost/pos/php/regprod.php" ><img src="http://localhost/pos/img/store/add-icon.png"></img></a>
```

I used the exact url to link the css file to regprod.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/pos/css/formstyle.css" />
```

It looks like this:

[image]

How am I suppose to put style on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JS instead of traditional CSS to acces remote iframe contents.
That'a an example of iframe access with jQuery :

```
var yourFrame = $(’#yourFrameId’);
yourFrame.load(function() {
    yourFrame.contents().find(’#yourElementInFrame’).css('display:block');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

put formstyle.css inside of mother page. Not the page you call with ajax.

fancybox fetches the content of regprod.php then puts in a div (infact mant divs.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer for future reference on the subject...  I've also found with fancybox to style in the HTML file you use in your iFrame.  This works well, if you don't want to mess with JavaScript.  I usually end up using both, but in this case I think that it would be very easy to use inline or internal CSS.  For example, here is a snippet for a fancybox form that works well:

```
<form style="font: normal 16px/1.3em Helvetica, Verdana, Arial;"
    id="ml-form" class="site-form" method="post" action="">

    <p style="font-weight: bold; color: #6d6e71; text-align: center;">
        Mailing list sign up form</p>

    <div style="display: none;">
        <p id="login_error">Please enter data below...</p>
    </div>

    <table style="font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;">

    . . .

</form>
```